# Oracle - Auditing for only some top-level statements

Tags: oracle, audit

I know that we can turn on auditing for all top-level statements using the following
`audit all statements`

I would like to continue logging only top-levels statements, but not all of them. For example, I dont want to audit `alter system`, `create cluster` etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I'm looking to do this for Exadata and Oracle 11 and 12

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support negative audit rules.

The only exception is the `EXCEPT` clause for Unified Audit policies which excludes the given users from auditing, but not statements.